# indexPath.row printing optional text

Tags: ios, swift

In a UITableView I'm trying to gather the value that the user is clicking on in the cell, so while testing it I'm just printing the value like so:

```
    print(the_object[indexPath.row])
```

But, it's being printed as "TheObject(name: Optional("Hello!"))", rather than just *Hello*.
Is there a solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
print(the_object[indexPath.row].name)
```

Comment: I had to change it to this:     print(student_object[indexPath.row].name ?? ""), but yes-- thank you!